# Does Domino's use rennet-free cheese?

Tags: cheese, vegetarian

Does Domino's pizza's use mozzarella cheese for their pizzas? If so,is it also rennet-free?

Comment: I would suspect that the answer to this could vary by country.

Comment: @DSingh2 Are you referring to Animal rennet, or rennet in general? If just animal, please edit question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the [nutritional information posted on their website](http://cache.dominos.com/express012904/pdf/nutri-info-wisconsin6.pdf) Domino's uses a blend of Mozzarella, American, Cheddar, Feta, Parmesan, and Provolone Cheeses.

Somebody, apparently, with similar concerns asked Domino's and [received this response](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100808164544AAdCEyD):

*excerpt from letter, emphasis added:*

> *Domino's Pizza Diced Cheese for Pizza* is a specially produced cheese
>   made exclusively for our use. It is a natural dairy product, produced
>   from cultured, pasteurized milk, *rennet*; and salts of calcium and/or
>   sodium. The type of rennet used in the production of this cheese is
>   restricted to a microbial-based rennet or a genetically-engineered
>   rennet. **Animal derived rennets will not be allowed**.
>
> As far as the *other cheeses* (Cheddar, Parmesan, Provolone, etc.),
>   **Domino's does not specify the source of rennet used in these products**.
>   They may or may not contain animal rennet. This depends on the
>   supplier's current source and is always subject to change without
>   notification to Domino's Pizza.

Comment: Thanks and hoping that Domino pizza should always use non animal rennet for their pizzas,specially for those vegetarians don't take animal rennet.

Answer (score 2):

Just an FYI there are 2 forms of rennet that are not animal rennet. Most cheeses are (and have to be...no option) coagulated with rennet...animal or vegetable or ... artificial...but still rennet.

So anyone who insists that their cheese be rennet free is limiting their choices to the types of cheeses that are "lactic acid coagulated" ...cheeses that DO NOT INCLUDE cheddars, parmesans, most mozzarellas, just about anything french or german or american, english, dutch.